# Can a possessive pronoun be used in a tag question?

Tags: grammaticality, question-tags

Can we use possessive pronouns in tag questions? For example,

> Your name is Ben, isn't yours?

Comment: Nope, you can't. That would be *..., isn't it?*

Comment: opps thanks but i think it has the same meaning

Comment: Your example is simply not grammatical, sorry.

Comment: You could say "My name is Kathrine, what's yours?" But not what you did say.

Comment: @Robusto: Yeah, and that's technically not a tag question...at least not according to the definition I learned.

Comment: I know that. I'm not sure the OP does, however.

Comment: @Robusto: Not quite, it seems.

Comment: @Cerberus that's a tag question. see the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question#Tag_questions_in_English)

Comment: @jlovegren: I don't know, it seems different to me. This is what your link says: *The English tag question is made up of an auxiliary verb and a pronoun.* — In *what's yours?*, I see two pronouns, and neither is of the conventional set *I/you/he/she/it/we/they/one/there*...perhaps I forgot some, but I think that it needs to be one of these, and only one. I don't have a problem with a new definition of *tag question* in principle, but then I would like another name for the more restricted type above.

Comment: @Cerberus well this is just a matter of semantics! i'm just treating this as a case of an improperly-formed tag question.

Comment: @jlovegren: A matter of semantics, haha, it is indeed, isn't it? By the way, I was replying to Robusto's example, not to Kathrine's, which I agree is best considered an improperly formed tag question.

Comment: You could also say *"My name's Katherine, isn't yours? Isn't everybody's?" and it'd be **closer to a properly formed tag question**, but a miss is as good as a mile.

Answer (score 6):

No, that would be incorrect. as Cerberus stated, the correct sentence would be "Your name is Ben, isn't it?" The correct pronoun to use in the tag question is the "it" not the possessive "yours."

Comment: Not even a possessive pronoun as the actual subject gets one in the tag: *Theirs is better, isn’t it?*

Answer (score 5):

It does sound weird. The tag question construction when formed from a clause with a [be] auxiliary or copula needs a subject pronoun to stand in. Not surprisingly, all the top hits in COCA are for the subject pronouns *it, you, they, he, we, she, they*. We also see expletive *there* showing up frequently when the tag is formed off of an existential *there* construction. There are, however, two hits that merit some scrutiny, `isn't that` and `isn't this`.

> , IS N'T IT ?                      4627  
>   , ARE N'T YOU ?           1214    
>    , WAS N'T IT ?               766 
>    , ARE N'T THEY ?         512 
>   , IS N'T HE ?                     413 
>    , ARE N'T WE ?             252 
>    , IS N'T SHE ?                  244 
>    , WERE N'T YOU ?      196 
>    , WAS N'T HE ?             191 
>    , IS N'T THERE ?        156 
>    , ARE N'T I ?                     147 
>    , WERE N'T THEY ?    114 
>   , WAS N'T SHE ?         89  
>    , ARE N'T THERE ?       49  
>    , WAS N'T I ?                   38  
>    , WAS N'T THERE ?     37  
>   , WERE N'T WE ?       29  
>    , WERE N'T THERE ?    10  
>    , ARE N'T YA ?                9   
>    , IS N'T THAT ?                1
>    , WERE N'T I ?               2
>   , IS N'T THIS ?                 1

Both of these come from talkshow transcripts, where people are speaking fast and constantly interrupting each other.

When we weed out the spurious uses of `isn't that`, one remains:

> That's OK. And we are talking now about a very modest goal of trying to get over 70 Democratic votes in the House out of 211. That's what we're talking about , is n't that ? You think you'll make over 70?

And the instance of `isn't this` is not spurious either:

> MR-GREGORY: Well, let me, let me, Secretary Duncan, let's, let's -- what do you see... SEC'Y-DUNCAN: Right. MR-GREGORY:... in the sense of the overall here? Because this is really the core , is n't this ? SEC'Y-DUNCAN: That's right. It is the core.

I wouldn't be surprised to find in very casual or incautious speech something like

> My daughter struggles with math, but yours isn't having any problems, isn't yours?

For a non-native speaker, though, steer clear!

Answer (score 2):

I can imagine a sentence like: "My dog is a dachshund, isn't yours?" but this would probably not technically qualify as a tag question.
We would absolutely never say, "My dog is beautiful, isn't mine?"

Answer (score 0):

Question tags consist of an auxiliary or modal verb or lexical verb be + subject pronoun. (Cambridge Grammar of English, section 300)

So we cannot use possessive. The subject of the sentence 'Your name is Ben' is 'your name' of which pronoun is 'it'. So the taq question might be 'isn't it'